# How to read a graph using Hashmap?

Tags: java

I got a [code](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~hzhang/c31/code/Graph.java) from this site and when i try to run i'm getting error in the HashMap.what's wrong with this?do i need to import anything?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Graph {

    private HashMap<String, Vertex> myVertices;
    private HashMap<Vertex, TreeSet<Vertex>> myAdjList;
    private static final TreeSet<Vertex> EMPTY_SET = new TreeSet<Vertex>();
    public static final int INFINITY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;


}
```

Error is

```
Graph1.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    private HashMap<String, Vertex> myVertices;
                            ^
  symbol:   class Vertex
  location: class Graph1
Graph1.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    private HashMap<Vertex, TreeSet<Vertex>> myAdjList;
```

Comment: @Tunaki    its not a duplicate one. i think i need to import some header file

Comment: Yes, this is specified as a potential cause in the linked question: *Perhaps you forgot to import the class.*.

Comment: which class? i got it from net